# WooCommerce - Function ID was called incorrectly. Order properties should not be accessed directly

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to update the order status in WooCommerce using a hook, but I get an PHP notice which says the following

`Notice: Function ID was called incorrectly. Order properties should not be accessed directly. auto_complete_specific_product_order, WC_Order->update_status, WC_Order->save, WC_Order->status_transition, do_action('woocommerce_order_status_completed'), WP_Ho in C:\Websites\mysite\www\wp-includes\functions.php on line 5865`

This is my function which seems to be triggering the PHP notice. I can't see exactly what I am doing incorrect, so any advice or suggestions would be appreciated.

```
// Hook the function to the order status change specifically for "completed"
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'transfer_product_status_complete', 10, 2);
function transfer_product_status_complete($order_id)
{
    global $wpdb;

    // Retrieve the order
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);

    // Check if the desired product is in the order
    $found = false;

    foreach ($order->get_items() as $item)
    {
        $product_id = $item->get_product_id();
        
        if ($product_id === 825 || $product_id === 885)
        {
            $found = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    // Execute the code only if the desired product is found
    if ($found)
    {
        // Retrieve the order user ID
        $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
        $new_owner_id = $order->get_user_id();

        // Retrieve and update custom fields when order becomes complete
        $serial_number_transfer = get_post_meta($order_id, 'serial_to_be_transferred', true);

        if (metadata_exists('post', $order_id, 'serial_to_be_transferred'))
        {
            // save the serial number
            update_post_meta($order_id, 'hash_data', $serial_number_transfer);

            // remove the serial from the custom field of the old owner 
            $orders = wc_get_orders(array(
                'customer' => $current_owner_id,
                'limit' => -1, // Retrieve all orders
            ));

            foreach ($orders as $order)
            {
                $order_id_sender = $order->ID;
                $serial_numbers = get_post_meta($order_id_sender, 'hash_data');

                $new_meta_value = str_replace($serial_number_transfer, '', $serial_numbers[0]);

                // Update the post meta with the new value
                update_post_meta($order_id_sender, 'hash_data', $new_meta_value);
            }

            // delete the custom field called serial_to_be_transferred
            delete_post_meta($order_id, 'serial_to_be_transferred');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tested your code and it is correct. No Order properties are accessed directly... So the problem come from something else.

Comment: I do this in the code afterwards: https://pastebin.com/THm4cmQa

Comment: No, this is still correct, and No Order properties are accessed directly... the problem still comes from something else.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. It is indeed another function causing the problem, and I managed to find it. I have updated my code to show it. This line in particular seems to be the cause `$order_id_sender = $order->ID;`. Using Lajos' code below, I should be able to just do `$order_id_sender = $order->get_id();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code somewhere is attempting to reach an order property like

```
$order->id
```

instead of

```
$order->get_id()
```

You will need to look at your stack trace and find where this happened and fix it accordingly. I do not know whether it was the `id` or some other property, because it did not happen in the code chunk you have shared. If you need further help, you will need to share more of your code, especially where order properties are attempted to be directly accessed.

Comment: How can I find the exact line which is causing the issue? The PHP notice says line 5865, but that is no help at all since I have all my custom theme PHP functions in-line in `functions.php`.

Comment: @matead you can refactor your code, break it up (there are also automatic tools that can do that for you) and retest.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your code fixed the problem (I was just showing the incorrect example code beforehand which I have since updated).

Comment: @matead I'm happy your problem has been resolved. You may decide accepting this answer as the correct answer if it indeed solved your problem. Happy programming!